# google drive error processing oauth 2 request 400

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth

we have several google oauth2 refresh tokens for Google Drive for which we always get the following error when trying to request a new access token:

```
POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Connection: close
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 208
Host: accounts.google.com

refresh_token=1%2FY5_2XY8uGujYa222rxXnsjR<snipped>&client_id=<clientid>&grant_type=refresh_token&client_secret=<clientsecret>
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Error processing OAuth 2 request
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Date: Tue, 20 Aug 2013 14:55:24 GMT

<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Error processing OAuth 2 request</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Error processing OAuth 2 request</H1>
<H2>Error 400</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

This only happens for some accounts, others work fine. The broken accounts fail reproducibly across days and weeks. Is there something wrong with the data we send? Any hint on what fails the validation?

I could provide you the tokens that are failing if necessary.

Comment: Send me an email with details. Assuming you can see the email address on the profile page, let me know if you don't.

Comment: @mariuss Unfortunately I can't see your email address. Where should I send it?

Comment: You will need to include the exact post request in your question.  Randomise some digits for security, but preserve the formatting, punctuation, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell all these refresh tokens fail because of invalid user accounts (deleted, disabled, etc). In these cases for all intents and purposes the token itself is invalid.

The HTML error response is a bug, and it should be fixed by now. Please report if you still see errors like this. The proper OAuth 2 error code in this case is "invalid_token".